# ListView data displayed in unusal format?

Tags: java, android, listview, object, arraylist

I am practicing this code from **head First Android Development**. Here , if i click on `Drink` from first list-view, it take me too 2nd list view where data is showing like **com.hfad.starbuzz.Drink@22c6250**

Can anyone please point out why it's presenting data like list way instead?

[1st list view link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KwEV.png)

[2nd list view looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dEPo.png)

**1st one pure java class to store array values and constructors.**

```
package com.hfad.starbuzz;

public class Drink {
private String name; private  String description; private int imgresourcesId;


public Drink(String name, String description, int imgresourcesId) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.imgresourcesId = imgresourcesId; }

public static final Drink [] drinks={
        new Drink("Latte", "Acouple of espresso shots with steamed milk ",
                R.drawable.latte),
         new Drink("Cupuuccino", "cup what is chino,, no ide ",
                 R.drawable.cappuccino),
         new Drink("filter", "all about filter ",
                 R.drawable.filter),
};



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getImgresourcesId() {
    return imgresourcesId;
}

public void setImgresourcesId(int imgresourcesId) {
    this.imgresourcesId = imgresourcesId;
}}
```

**1)Main Activity Class**

```
package com.hfad.starbuzz;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView,
                                View itemView,
                                int position,
                                long id) {
            if (position==0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DrinkCategoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            }
        };
    ListView listView =findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

    }}
```

**main activity Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/startbuzz"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/option"
    >
 </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**and 2nd list view Class. it does not have any Layout file** .

```
package com.hfad.starbuzz;

public class DrinkCategoryActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView listDrinks = getListView();
    ArrayAdapter<Drink> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Drink>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Drink.drinks);
    listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView,
                            View itemView,
                            int position,
                            long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DrinkCategoryActivity.this, DrinkActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKNO, (int) id);
    startActivity(intent);
    }}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to achieve that the drink names are listed? If this is the case, try overriding the toString method

Comment: it worked perfectly. thanks a lot

Comment: If you found a good answer to your own question, then please make it an answer, instead of confusing people by giving the answer inside the question. Also, do not edit titles to "solved" or anything. The question stays. An answer can be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved ,

I have just added toString method inside the class that contains array values like below :-

```
 public String getName() {


    return name;
}
@Override
public String toString (){
    return name;
}
```